# Why does the original array change when I am changing the value returned from find()

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const courses = [
    {'id':101,'name':'Complete Web Dev'},
    {'id':102,'name':'DS and Algo'},
    {'id':103,'name':'React'}
];

let num = courses.find(c=>{
  if(c.id===102)
    return c;
});

num.name="Programming Fundamentals"
console.log(courses);
```

Can anyone please explain to me that when I am changing the value returned from the find function then why do the values inside the original array changes? Is there a concept that I am missing?
After executing the code I am getting the below-mentioned output.

```
[
  { id: 101, name: 'Complete Web Dev' },
  { id: 102, name: 'Programming Fundamentals' },
  { id: 103, name: 'React' }
]
```

Comment: Short anser: simple types are 'call by value' whereas objects and arrays are 'call by reference'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are referencing the same object. In JavaScript only the [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) values get passed by value. If you want it to be a different object then you can copy it.

One way of doing that is [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the object and assigning it again.

```
num = {...num}
```

Keep in mind that spreading an object is a shallow copy, meaning that if you have a nested object then it won't be copied but referenced.